# How can I Group ruby objects based on the next values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Ok so I have this array of objects

```
pry(main)> @something.objects
=> [#<Object id: 2, position: 1, some_type: "Header", entryable_id: 6>,
=> [#<Object id: 3, position: 2, some_type: "Content", entryable_id: 32>,
=> [#<Object id: 4, position: 3, some_type: "Content", entryable_id: 11>,
=> [#<Object id: 6, position: 4, some_type: "Header", entryable_id: 15>,
=> [#<Object id: 7, position: 5, some_type: "Content", entryable_id: 41>,
=> [#<Object id: 8, position: 6, some_type: "Header", entryable_id: 109>,
```

What I want is the Headers grouped with the next Content like

```
[{
  header: #<Object id: 2, position: 1, some_type: "Header", entryable_id: 6, 
  content: [#<Object id: 3, position: 2, some_type: "Content", entryable_id: 32>, #<Object   id: 4, position: 3, some_type: "Content", entryable_id: 11>]}, 
  header: #<Object id: 6, position: 4, some_type: "Header", entryable_id: 15>, 
  content: [#<Object id: 7, position: 5, some_type: "Content", entryable_id: 41>],
  content: #<Object id: 8, position: 6, some_type: "Header", entryable_id: 109>
]
```

So basically the objects all have a position and I want to group all the Headers with the next "Content" until another header comes along...I was thinking of just looping over the objects and creating an array of hashes but I wanted to know if there is an optimal way of doing with, maybe with the DB or another approach

Comment: we can't run this, give some sample data, to get the ideas from us..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) is what you are looking for.

```
@something.slice_before {|e| e.some_type == "Header"}.flat_map { |h, *c| {:header => h, :content => c} }
```

Comment: +1 This is essentially what the OP is looking for. Here's a quick example to illustrate: `[1,2,3,'a',4,5,6,'a',7,8,9,'a',1,3,5].slice_before {|i| i == 'a'}.to_a`

Comment: I would add  `.flat_map { |h, *c| {:header => h, :content => c} }` to match the question